# How can i add a drop dow menu in flutter chips?

Tags: flutter, dart

There isn't much code to add here , but i am trying to achieve something like this, is there any package or code for this ? Basically a chip widget with drop dow meu

[image],

here is the video [flutterchips with dropdow](https://m3.material.io/components/chips/guidelines#dcf3eb06-5f81-4f7d-8299-e32a950d8572)

Comment: Just put a dropdown in a chip?

Comment: Tried but my skill level are not up to the standards.

Comment: you can find more on `menus` in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MenuBar-class.html . Try to integrate that with chips.

Answer (score 0):

Check the example code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'IconTextDropdown Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [
    buildDropdownItem(Icons.home, 'Option 1'),
    buildDropdownItem(Icons.business, 'Option 2'),
    buildDropdownItem(Icons.business, 'Option 3'),
    buildDropdownItem(Icons.business, 'Option 4'),
  ];

  String selectedValue = 'option1'; 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('IconTextDropdown Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: IconTextDropdown(
          items: dropdownItems,
          onChanged: (String? value) {
            if (value != null) {
              setState(() {
                selectedValue = value;
              });
            }
          },
          value: selectedValue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static DropdownMenuItem<String> buildDropdownItem(IconData icon, String text) {
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      value: text,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(icon), 
          SizedBox(width: 8),
          Text(text),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IconTextDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  final String value;

  IconTextDropdown({
    required this.items,
    required this.onChanged,
    required this.value,
  });

  @override
  _IconTextDropdownState createState() => _IconTextDropdownState();
}

class _IconTextDropdownState extends State<IconTextDropdown> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: widget.value,
      onChanged: widget.onChanged,
      items: widget.items,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down), 
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      underline: Container(
        height: 1,
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thnx, but the question is specifically related to chips